# Poor-man's backup to multiple sources (DVD, hard-drive)

Tags: backup

I'd like to organise my data backup, but it's hard to understand which software supports the case I want.

I'd like plain static backup DVDs (for some static large files) and the system should catalog which files I've already saved (and maybe even tell on which DVD). I'd like to know which files haven't been burned to DVD so I can open a new DVD.
But all this is only for particular folders with large content. At the same time all the other folders should be synchronized to an external harddrive.

Any idea how to set up such a system which would work on Linux and Windows? Is there a program for that?

Comment: Burning to DVD's is soo 1999. Get two external harddrives, a friend willing to let you back up to them and use crashplan.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not married to backing up to DVD, [CrashPlan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/) offers a free solution that provides backup to several types of destinations (eg. external disks, folders, other pcs).